# Axis2 1.6.2 WebService Issue with WebSphere Network Deployment 8.5.5.0

Tags: java, jsf, apache-axis, websphere-8, apache-commons-fileupload

I have a **JSF**+Richfaces based application that has **Axis2 1.6.2** SOAP Webservice implemented on JDK6. The application works fine when I deploy it in Tomcat 6 or 7. But when we deploy it in **WebSphere 8.5.5 Network Deployment** it gives following error whenever we try to start the application:

```
[9/28/20 17:02:26:798 PKT] 00000040 WarBasedAxisC E org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator <init> org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
                                 org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processMessageBuilders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:774)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:234)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:859)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.<init>(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:569)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:338)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1363)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:606)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:576)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:425)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1175)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2182)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:994)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:93)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:170)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1564)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DescriptionBuilder.processMessageBuilders(DescriptionBuilder.java:230)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processMessageBuilders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:771)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
    ... 37 more

[9/28/20 17:02:26:811 PKT] 00000040 AxisServlet   I org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger info org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
[9/28/20 17:02:26:896 PKT] 00000040 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_ad76d55e_20.09.28_17.02.26.838698289724018241690.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletInstance.init 172
[9/28/20 17:02:26:906 PKT] 00000040 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
[9/28/20 17:02:26:908 PKT] 00000040 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp commonInitializationFinally SRVE0266E: Error occured while initializing servlets: {0}
                                 javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:490)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:338)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1363)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:606)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:576)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:425)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1175)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2182)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:994)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:576)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:457)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processMessageBuilders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:774)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:234)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:859)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.<init>(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:569)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:93)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:170)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1564)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DescriptionBuilder.processMessageBuilders(DescriptionBuilder.java:230)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processMessageBuilders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:771)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
    ... 37 more
```

I have done a very detailed research on the issue and found that Websphere has its own Axis library and to over ride this, Class loader should be configured to Parent last. I also tried to deploy the sample Axis2 1.6.2 application by following steps given in url just to make sure is Axis2 1.6.2 works or not:
http://manishcusat68.blogspot.com/2015/08/axis2-installation-in-websphere.html

The sample application is deployed and I am able to see the wsdl file.
I am using the same version of axis2 i.e 1.6.2 in my application but I always get the above exception and application never starts.
I have searched every forum, have tried each and every step I found on IBM Websphere website/stackoverflow but I am not able to find any solution of this.
I tried by putting commons-fileupload jar in lib/ext but it didn't work.
I tried to add the patch of commom-fileupload jar in system environment path but it didn't work either.
I have also tried to delete jars from IBM installation/plugin folder as per suggestions in many forums and put commons-fileupload jar in my application/lib but Websphere didn't start.
I desperately need the solution of that and request assistance from any expert please.

Comment: Have you tried to get rid of all axis 2 libraries from your app and use internal WAS WS engine?

Comment: I have tried it. I removed axis2 related jars from project lib to use WebSphere's default axis2 but still I got the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

There's a JVM property to disable the JAXWS engine that's built into WAS.  It's not perfect but it would be worth a try if you haven't already.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html

Comment: I have already done that. Still I am getting same exception.